# File recover tool for a partially "repaired" drive

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, data-recovery

An employee here recently had her hard drive corrupted pretty bad.  I ran `chkdsk /F` on it to try and restore what I could, but during this it removed all the indexes for the My Documents folder.  I know there has to be software out there that could recover the data, but I searched and saw several threads here regarding partition recovery or undelete tools and was unsure if these are what I want or if I need to use something different.  Tips and advice are also helpful, I've never recovered a drive before.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For data recovery my company typically uses [Runtime's](http://www.runtime.org/) GetDataBack software.  I've used it to recover data from multiple disks that have been formatted, corrupted, or completely wiped and reinstalled.  They've got a free trial available, so feel free to give it a shot!

Answer (score 1):

my tool of choice:

> **[WinHex](http://www.x-ways.net/winhex/)** is in its core a universal hexadecimal editor,
>   particularly helpful in the realm of
>   computer forensics, data recovery,
>   low-level data processing, and IT
>   security. An advanced tool for
>   everyday and emergency use: inspect
>   and edit all kinds of files, recover
>   deleted files or lost data from hard
>   drives with corrupt file systems.

if it is only file recovery you're interested in, then the 'lite' variant should suffice, it is based on the very same technology:

> **[Davory](http://www.x-ways.net/davory/index-m.html)** undeletes files and recovers files from logically
>   corrupted or formatted drives.
>   Incorporates some of the data recovery
>   techniques from WinHex  and
>   **concentrates on ease of use**.

Davory is very easy to use indeed, select the drive, specify your output folder (on another drive), search by filename (use the wildcard `*.*`) and let it work its magic.

Answer (score 1):

I've used [ActiveFileRecovery](http://www.file-recovery.net/) with great success in the past - highly recommended.

Answer (score 0):

You could boot using livecd like BartPE and recover data into USB drive.

Comment: A BartPE CD does nothing for you in the realm of data recovery, not without additional programs.

Comment: Using BartPE i could recover and copy almost all my data from non-bootable OS into USB flash drive without any extra program. It would detect the hard disk and then You can copy/paste from explorer window.